# End a background process by executing it again in another console, how can it be done?

Tags: c, ipc, daemon

I have a program in C that is required to run in the background. It mimics the smartfolder that you can find on OSX.

I have been asked to <strike>kill</strike> end it by writing it's execution command a second time in a console.

I thought about saving the pid and using 2nd program to watch for the input but I did not find a way to send the input to a background process.

I've tried using pipe and the background program was reading from it but the inputs were not going to it.

Could someone tell me if it's possible at all and if this is the right way to do it ? Would this work with a daemon process too ?

Comment: What's wrong with pipes? 
You can try with sockets, anyway, sockets should work.

Comment: Assuming "*kill*" to mean  "*end*" then yes, it's possible in ,multiple ways. signals and/or a pipe are definitely possible ways to go.

Comment: yes i meant end , is it possible even if the process is a deamon ?

Comment: Yes. A "*daemon*" process in the first place is  ... well, just another process running.

Comment: search for [IPC](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=inter+process+communication)

Answer (score 1):

If you save the PID in a file somewhere, what about just running

```
kill(pid, SIGTERM);
```

If you need special cleanup upon handling (like deleting the file in which you store the PID), implement a handler for the TERM signal (see the `signal` function).

Alternatively, you could use a user signal, `SIGUSR1`, for instance.

Comment: Thanks.
I need to match the pid to the name of the smartfolder . that's why i need a 2nd process. I will save the pid and name of the smartfolder in a file that I will read with the 2 nd process, if it see a matching name in the stdin it need to end the matching process. 
Can I redirect stdin to a pipe from inside the deamon without admin right ?

Comment: @Ashuiegi I'm not sure I understand: you can have several processes at the same time, each for a different directory ?

Comment: exactly and by typing in a console ./smartfolder /foldername/  it should end the corresponding daemon.
You have one folder that is being searched and one folder where the symlinks goes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really close to make it work, just my kill function not working but i have the PID of the smartfolder process.

I did the following : if the program is executed with more then 1 arguments, it run the smartfolder which save it's pid to a file.

if it has only one argument, it goes read the txt file named the same as the smartfolder dir to find the PID and send a kill signal with it.

this way when I enter the execution command with only 1 argument it will kill the corresponding process!